# Building a database-aware application with PRISM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, architecture, prism

I am building an application using WPF, MVVM, and PRISM. the application is an intensive CRUD app, and the db is accessed using entity framework. i want to build the application using modules but i can't figure out where to put the data access code (more accurately i can't figure out where to put the repository interface) . if they go into an infrastructure project. then all modules will depend on that and it doesn't seem like the right place. on the other hand if the interfaces go into their respective modules then there will be lots of inter-dependencies between the modules which is bad.
Question: best way of designing a database-aware modular PRISM MVVM application and perhaps the best solution to my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to read [official Prism guide](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/55580).

I use this separation:

- `MyApp` - shell project
- `MyApp.Infrastructure` - all shared **interfaces** - including your `IRepository`
- `MyApp.DAL` - contains all DAL classes, and also `Repository` implementation
- `MyApp.Modules.SimpleModule`
- `MyApp.Modules.AnotherModel`
- etc.

Main thing about modules - they should not depend **on each other**, but they could depend on shared modules (e.g. `MyApp.Infrastructure`).

Answer (score 2):

I think you may take a look at [MEF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/09/29/simple-introduction-to-composite-applications-with-the-managed-extensions-framework.aspx). It allows you to have the level of abstraction and modularity you will need for this while everything working together in a seamless way.

Comment: MEF is just another DI container, and i need to get this working on an architectural level.

Comment: "MEF is just another DI container" - not true. Its much more than that, you can throw any assemblies in your application bin folder and MEFs loads that at runtime, you can also make your repository infrastructure a "part" in MEF, and your modules would have no direct dependency on it.

Comment: sorry i didn't know that. can you provide a link to some article or blog about the last part "make your repositry infrastructure a "part" in MEF".

Comment: [here](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=130) is an introductory tutorial about MEF. It basically explains how to create different "parts" and how to make them work together